# Query: Developing a Malware Detection App

Tags: android

I was intending to have a MSc student investigate the detection of Malware for example Botnet activity on Android.

My intension is to have the student develop and test his/her botnet simulation and botnet detector/mitigation app using the Android Emulator in Eclipse.

From reading posts about rooting the emulator, there seems to be conflicting statements that say it can be rooted or it can't be rooted.

One may adopt an approach where by iptables maybe used as part of the botnet mitigation process perhaps blocking IRC ports or filtering for layer-7 strings.

I have seen some threads with respect to rooting the emulator in eclipse (for iptables) and there seems to be an issue with it.

I want to be sure that the Android Emulator in the Eclipse IDE may be used to develop an app to, for example detect various IRC ports and perhaps have iptables block such ports or block certain IRC commands using iptables string match etc.

All comments are welcome,
Patrick

Comment: IRC bots are not a reall bot for my opinion :) thats just using for ddos, or have some more functionality bots and like that bots cannot  be more then 20K or a little bit more, because of the server limit! reall botnets are more complex, and a p2p application on same time like as skype or msn ! and like that bots don't have max value or server limit! even just 1 people can own 2 millions bots in all around the world. And they are so smart for bypass antivirus for port blocking : if 80 is available they can use 80 like as skype :)

Comment: they don't like all antivirus and they are using "fud crypter technologies" now the antiviruses cannot see it anymore :) they can send 300 or 400 millions email just in 1 day and around 80% can going to inbox in the email boxes, they know the what's mean the spam for gmail or hotmail or yahoo ? How they know this is spam, in same time the attacker know it too.

Comment: if they have like that huge bots, you newer know its bot or not ! because maybe he just send 5 or max 10 emails with your computer but cross it to all his bots network count, he can sale shit, even he want :))

Comment: I think you newer know, like that bots :) because the bots just send email not to much email and just visit some website over google search. And just he do something like that activities! Can you find like that bots ? if you have some idea, we can share our ideas each other

Comment: My all comments for not just for pc :)